# Confused about open set

Tags: general-topology

This statement appears in book : {0} is not open in R. But according to the definition of open, I can find an open ball centered at 0 lies in R,  should it be open?

Comment: Set $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ is open if for every $a \in A$ there is an oben ball $B(a,r) \subset A$. Now $A = \{0\}$. You can't find an open ball $B(0,r)$ that is a subset of the set $\{0\}$.

Comment: Read the definition of open again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A set $S$ is said to be open if there exists an open ball $B$ contained in $A$.

Suppose $B$ is an open ball of radius $\epsilon$ contained in $\left\{0\right\}$. Clearly, this ball must be centered at zero for otherwise it would contain some nonzero point. It follows that the point $\epsilon/2$ is in this ball and we arrive at a contradiction; no such ball exists.